# Passing variable from invoked Lambda Function to DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to invoke a string from another lambda function. This string should be written into an array which is then uploaded to a DynamoDB Table along with information such as the date.

Yet when I try to get the variable called **"key"** in the lower part of the script where it is supposed to upload to DynamoDB, it is undefined and not written into the table.

I tried using the *window.variable* command but somehow AWS lambda didn't recognize it. All in all I'm quite new and a bit confused on how to pass variables between different functions within in a JavaScript.

Maybe someone can help me. Thank you!

```js
var key;    //define key as gloabal variable
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');   //load aws-sdk
AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1'; //Set server region
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();      
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-central-1'});   //region of dynamo server



exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
    FunctionName: 'string_Generator', // called Function
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  };
  
  lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      context.fail(err);
    } else {
      context.succeed(data.Payload);
      
    }
    
    key = data.Payload;   //set the payload/string as "key" variable
   
  });
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var params = {
        Item: {
            date: Date.now(),
            Key: key
        },
        TableName: 'Productkeys'
    };
    params.Item.partitionkey = "3";         //putting in the partition key of the DynamoServer
    return await db.put(params).promise();
    

}
```

Comment: Both of your functions have the same name ("handler"), you are overwriting it by declaring it twice. That is one of the issues.

Comment: @kuchenesser is your problem cleared

Comment: @SaiSreenivas no. I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you are overwriting your `handler` function, because you have 2 functions with the same name. The other thing is it looks like this might be better in one function, as one depends on the other and I don't know how you are calling them or from where.

Try this:

```js
exports.handler = async () => {
    var params = {
        FunctionName: 'string_Generator', // called Function
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    };
    
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            context.succeed(data.Payload);  
        }

        var params2 = {
            Item: {
                date: Date.now(),
                Key: data.Payload
            },
            TableName: 'Productkeys'
        };
        params2.Item.partitionkey = "3";
        return await db.put(params2).promise();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and moved the *return await d.put(params).promise();* line one down because it was showing a compiler error. 
Yet I'm getting this error now:

**    "MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:",
    "* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'TableName' in params",
    "* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Item' in params",**

I'm not sure of this is about the upper params or the lower params function. But it doesnt really make sense to me, since Item and Tablename are defined in the same way as before, where it worked.

Comment: @kuchenesser Try now.

Comment: Yeah. I think it tried to get the params from above and put it into the DynamoDB. Yet this code had a compiler error until I deleted the *await* behind the *return*. So something somewhere still went wrong. I'm not getting a compiler error anymore but it also wont upload to the Table. Thank your for your help.

Comment: @ffritz it's not advisable you return it directly. Put the response of put statement into a variable and then return it. This is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I went through it the whole night but I was able to fix it with @ffritz advice.

I tried some different combinations and tried to understand the syntax a lot better until it finally worked out. It might not be the prettiest code but it **works**.

Thank you for your help guys.

Edit: I found one more issue. The code doesnt get executed immediately. The generated keys just stay in the function and are deployed upon the next call. So when I'm calling the function via API Gateway, I dont deploy the freshly generated string, but the old one. I still need to find a fix for that.

Edit 2: Now it works. I updated the script below.

```html
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');         //load aws sdk
AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';   //Server of Lambda 
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();  
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-central-1'});   //region of DB Server


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    
    var params = {                                                  //set parameters for the call 
        FunctionName: 'String_Generator',                           // called Function
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    };
   
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {                     //Invoke other function
        if (err) {
            context.fail(err);
        } else {                                                    //if invoke gets string
                                    
                var params2 = {                                     //set parameters for DB put
                    Item: {
                        date: Date.now(),
                        Key: data.Payload                           //set the string as "Key" variable
                        },
                    TableName: 'Productkeys'         
                };
            params2.Item.partitionkey = data.Payload;               //add the partition key
            db.put(params2);                                        //put the params2 into the DB
            callback(null, data.Payload);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: So are you saying if I execute code then the generated string is of the previous call?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas yes exactly.

Comment: Just check whether your function is invoking multiple times (with same/diff req id). It might happen when your function times out. So check whether any of these is happening.